# Javascript Array function has bug I cannot see

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a function which should create a 2 dimensional array pre-populated with zeros.  My output looks correct, but apparently there is a bug in it that I am not seeing.  Does anybody know what it is?  I don't see it.

```
function createMatrix(size) {
    var defValue = 0;
    var row = [];
    var matrix = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        row.push(defValue);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        matrix.push(row);
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: What happens that makes you think there is a bug? You need to be a bit more descriptive. The only issue I see so far is that every array in matrix is a reference to the same array.

Comment: It's an extra exercise I'm working on for class; my teacher tells me there is something I am missing.

Comment: `matrix.push(row.slice());` Would fix it, but @nderscore answer is neater.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're pushing the same `row` into your array `matrix` every time. These all point to the same array, since they are passed by reference.

You should make a new array for each row instead:

```js
function createMatrix(size){
    var defValue = 0;
    var matrix = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) { 
            row.push(defValue); 
        }
        matrix.push(row); 
    }  
    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the second loop;

If you stop and trace your code, you can see that you are only creating one "row" array whereas you most likely want to make size amount of rows.

Your code should probably look like this

```
var matrix = [];
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    //temp row to append to array
    var row = [];

    //fill row array with 0s
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
       row.push(0);
    }

    //append row to the matrix
    matrix.push(row);
}
return matrix
```

This way you are pushing a completed row at the end of each iteration.